# passing a variable through a DOM content of a <td> element to be used in a msqli query inside a modal

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom

I dont know if my title is really clear but I have a calendar thats formatted into a table with each day in a  with the date stored in the DOM element like so

```
<td data-event="'.$currentDay.'" class="empty'.$style.' hidden-xs">'.$day .'</br></br></br>&nbsp;</td>
```

The data-event tag contains the date.

Then using javascript I do this:

```
$('.empty').on('click', function(){
   var event = $(this).find('a').data('event');
   var choosen_date = $(this).data('event');
   $('#event-data').val(choosen_date);
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Now I can call the variable in my modal by doing this:

```
<input id="event-data" type="text" name="date" value="" />
```

My question is this: Is there a way of calling in the data from that DOM element so I can use it in a mysqli query like so?

```
$qry = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM events WHERE date = 'the dom variable would be here'")
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You are using PHP on one sid, so what you should do is a async request on your PHP file sending the value through $_POST, $_GET.

Then execute the PHP with the sent variable.
And return the result (in JSON for example)

Finally, do what you want with the result on the application/web page.

Sync and Asyn requests: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

or better in jQuery:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/